# Rails4で同じアクションに対するURLが複数あるようなルーティング設定は良い/悪い？

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

例えば、`UsersController`というのがあったとして、`config/routes.rb`で、以下のように設定したとします。

```
root 'users#index' # rootはuserの一覧にしたい
resources :users
```

そうすると、ルーティングの設定は以下のようになると思います。

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action    
        root GET    /                         users#index       
       users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
       users POST   /users(.:format)          users#create      
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new         
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit        
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show        
             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update      
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update      
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

このとき、`users#index` に対応するURL(GET)が `/` と `/users` の複数存在することになります。
こういう状態は 有り or 無し どちらとするべきなのでしょうか？

気持ち悪かったので `except` や `only` を使って一意のURLになるようにしていたんですが、
Web上のチュートリアルやサンプルコードなどではそのまま複数ある状態になっていたので・・・
確かに、デフォルトの設定に沿った名前付きルートがそのまま使えるのは利点な気もします。

Answer (score 5):

もしその URL を公開しているであれば、SEO の観点からみると URL はコンテンツと一対一の方がいいと聞いた事があります。

コンテンツが重複する場合、下記サイトを参考に`rel=canonical`属性を付けた方がいいかもしれません。

[rel=canonical 属性に関する 5 つのよくある間違い](http://googlewebmastercentral-ja.blogspot.jp/2013/05/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。SEOのことも頭にあって、そのあたりも考慮した総合的なベストプラクティスが聞ければ嬉しいな、という気持ちもありましたので助かります。
公開するかどうかというのは確かにまず基準になりそうですね。
そもそもレイヤーをわけて、canonicalizationはRailsでどうこう考えるより、フロントに置くWebサーバー側でリダイレクトとかさせる方が良いのかもしれませんね。

Comment: そうですね、出来るのであればリダイレクトが一番いいかもしれませんね！

Answer (score 1):

命名則に従ったURLが使える利点はあるので、問題がないなら残して置いて良いのでは。
複数人で開発するときには参照しているアドレスがまちまちでメンテの時のトラブルの原因になる、といった事も考えられるので、そういう時は明示的に潰しておいてもよいかもしれません。